# How to distinguish between user action and code action in android Spinner class?

Tags: android, android-spinner, onitemclicklistener, onitemselectedlistener

I need to distinguish user action from code action in android spinner.
To do this, I just wanna use onItemClickListener but it occurs runtime exception. So I have to use onItemSelectedListener and have no idea to distinguish the user action.
What should I do now?